# JavaScript: change all duplicated elements in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, replace, compare

I have an array like this

```
var array=[[1,'a'],[1,'b'],[2,'c'],[2,'b'],[2,'d'],[3,'a'],[3,'s'],[3,'w'],[3,'q'],[4,'w']]
```

and the output I want to be following:

```
1   a
    b
2   c
    b
    d
3   a
```

and so on. So I want to replace all dublicate numbers with `''`.

Tried this, but it compares only two elements.

```
for( var i=0; i<array.length-1; i++ ) {
        if ( array[i][0] == array[i+1][0] ) {
            array[i+1][0]='';
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add external loop:

```
   for(var j=0; j < array.length; j++){
for( var i=0; i<array.length; i++ ) {
        if ( array[i][0] == array[j][0] && i != j) {
            array[i][0]='';
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Following code print data in the format shown in your question, but data is not modified.

```
//print first data
println( string(array[0][0]) + '  ' + array[0][1] )
var prevNumber = array[0][0]  // record the number of data printed last.

for( var i=1; i<array.length-1; i++ ) {
    if ( array[i][0] == prevNumber ) {  // if same number, print ' ' instead of number.
        println( ' ' + '   ' + array[i][1] )
    } else { // number is changed
        println( array[i][0] + '   ' + array[i][1] )
        prevNumber = array[i][0]  // record the number of data printed last.
    }
}
```

It is easy to delate a part of data in array, but it is difficult or impossible to restore tha data deleted afterward. This is why I don't modify data of the array but modify the code to print.